# How to calculate remainder of percent operation?

Tags: java, algorithm

I would like to calculate simple modulo operation, but assuming my divisor is a percent value. Simple example:

```
50 mod 20% = 0
51 mod 20% = 1
52 mod 20% = 2
53 mod 20% = 3
54 mod 20% = 4
55 mod 20% = 0
```

In this case it is simple `number mod 5`, but with other percents (e.g. 75%) it is not so easliy converted. It seems like it should be simple reminder operation, but the closest things I managed to get is this:

```
public long modulo(BigDecimal number, BigDecimal percentage) {
        BigDecimal flooredPercentValue = number.multiply(percentage).divide(HUNDRED, 0, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
        BigDecimal valueThatPercentIsInteger = flooredPercentValue.multiply(HUNDRED)
                .divide(percentage, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        return number.subtract(valueThatPercentIsInteger).longValue();
}
```

Could it be done in more simple way?

Comment: Could you explain what "mod 20%" means, and why it maps to "mod 5"? I don't understand the operation. Some context about the purpose of this calculation would help.

Comment: At a guess, he's converting 20% to a decimal, 0.2, and then to a fraction, 1/5.  So that's where "divide by 5" comes from.

Comment: Or he means 20% of the left hand side, rounded down? So 50 mod 20% will be 50 mod 10, for 55 it will be mod 11? Unclear..

Comment: `number % (percent / 100.0) = result` -> `50 % (20 / 100.0) = 0`

Comment: Okey, some context: I have some number of items. I would like to divide them into several buckets (e.g. 5% to the first, 15% to the second, 80% to the third). Items are indivisible. To calculate this precisely there could be a situation where we need to put some items aside (not placing them in any bucket), because it would screw the percents up. How to calculate the number of items that are divisible within these buckets.

Comment: That seems a kind of X-Y problem to me (see [Meta Stack Exchange – What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)) – you think you can solve the problem X with a method Y and you ask how to implement Y. But it's much better to present X first, and see if somebody finds a simpler or/and more effective way to solve it than Y...

Comment: To solve this I calculate greates common divisor (in example above it is 5%) and find "modulo" of this value.

Comment: 5 % or 20 %?? Aren’t you contradicting yourself now?

Comment: That makes no sense.  How do you get a "common divisor" out of 53, a prime number?

Comment: Greatest common divisor from 5, 15 and 80. I meant example from my comment, not my post.

Comment: So what about your post then?

Comment: Example in my post might occur for example when you have 50/51/52/53/54/55 items and GCD is 20, meaning you have to split the items into two buckets 20% and 80%. GCD is 20 then.

Comment: Example - two buckets 20% to the first, 80% to the second. When you want to place there 52 items, you can put 10 in the first, 40 in the second and put 2 aside.

Comment: What do you do if the split is 19% and 81%?

Comment: Then you can not place any items in the buckets to meet the requirements. Any placement would be incorrect - you put all the items aside. GCD = 1. 52 mod 1% = 52.

Comment: @Fuv why `1%` though? this doesn't make any sense

Comment: You have split 19%/81%. If number of items is indivisible then 1% of your items must be greater than one. Otherwise the split is not possible. For example if you have 100 items, you can divide them into 19/81 and none left aside. If you have 101 items - 19/81 and 1 aside. But if you have 99 (and less) then no placement is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I see I was right: you made percents your main problem, while they do not matter actually, or even they do not exist.

The problem is:

- given a natural (positive) number N of some items and a natural number B of buckets; and given B natural numbers x,y, ... z;
- decompose N into a sum of B+1 whole (non-negative) terms: N = Nx + Ny + … + Nz + R
- in such a way that terms Nx … Nz preserve predefined ratios:
  Nx : Ny : … : Nz = x : y : … : z,
  or they are all zeros
- while the remainder R is as small as possible.

Which is equivalent to:

- distribute as much as possible of N items into B buckets preserving strictly given ratios of numbers of items in each bucket.

Of course x,y,…z *can* sum up to 100 and then they can be considered 'percentages', but the general formulation allows also ratios like 5:9 or 2:7:13:15, which can not be expressed with percents.

The problem could be solved 'manually' this way:

1. reduce x, y, … z by their greatest common divisor (so that 20:80 becomes 1:4);
2. take x, y … and z items from the pool
3. did step 2. succeed (i.e., there were at least x+y+…+z items)?
4. if so, put items into respective buckets and re-iterate from 2.
5. otherwise stop.

To do that faster we can replace the iterated subtraction with division:

1. reduce x, y, … z by their greatest common divisor (so that 20:80 becomes 1:4);
2. calculate the minimum number M of items which allow correct distribution over buckets
   M = x + y + … + z;
3. calculate ratio F = floor(N/M) and remainder R = N modulo M;
4. put R items aside
5. distribute the rest as F·x, F·y, …, F·z.